# Spring Web Service create DomPoxMessage instead of SaajSoapMessage

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I am using Spring web service and the spring web service/xml version is 2.1.3, yet the other spring core version is 3.2.3.  I need to access the soap header and set the response header the same as the request header.  I extended the PayloadValidationInterceptor to add extra logic as below:

```
@Override
public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint,
        Exception ex) {
    //System.out.println("afterCompletion");
    SaajSoapMessage soapRequest = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext
            .getRequest();
    SoapHeader reqheader = soapRequest.getSoapHeader();
    SaajSoapMessage soapResponse = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext
            .getResponse();
    SoapHeader respheader = soapResponse.getSoapHeader();
    if( reqheader !=null ){
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
            .newInstance();
        try {
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            Iterator<SoapHeaderElement> itr = reqheader
                    .examineAllHeaderElements();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                SoapHeaderElement ele = itr.next();
                transformer.transform(ele.getSource(), respheader.getResult());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(Toolkit.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }

}
```

And in the spring web service configuration, I have added the following message factory to make sure that SAAJ Soap message is used.

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

When testing, thing are normal.  But now in production when the work load is high, I started to receive ClassCastException as messageContext.getRequest() returns a DomPoxMessage instead of SaajSoapMessage.  Does anyone know why it happens like that.

Comment: the actual error might be useful

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the information that you have provided, I cannot get to the exact reason. But to avoid this problem you can use the constructor of [SAAJSOAPMessageFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/saaj/SaajSoapMessageFactory.html#SaajSoapMessageFactory%28javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory%29) that takes the message factory as the argument. This way you can be sure that only SaajSoapMessageFactory is used. The way jdk looks for an appropriate soap factory is by searching first for jaxm.properties in java home or else looks up a suitable implementation in classpath [ref](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/xml/soap/FactoryFinder.java#FactoryFinder.find%28java.lang.String%29).